# ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js

Tags: reactjs, axios

**I get this error after installing and importing axios in my react project, any help?:**

Compiled with problems:

**ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js 11:11-26**

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters'
Did you mean './http'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
- install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

**ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js 13:12-28**

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
- install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

**ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js 19:10-24**

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
- install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

**ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js 21:11-26**

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
- install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }

**ERROR in ./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js 1:10-24**

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules\follow-redirects'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
- install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

**ERROR in ./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js 5:11-26**

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules\follow-redirects'
Did you mean './http'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
- install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

**ERROR in ./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js 7:12-28**

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules\follow-redirects'
Did you mean './https'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
- install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

**ERROR in ./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js 9:15-41**

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules\follow-redirects'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

**ERROR in ./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js 11:13-30**

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'H:\Github\arshwy\reactjs-laravel-simple-dashboard\frontend-react\node_modules\follow-redirects'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
- install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }

Comment: This is not the full error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @tkausl , thank you i edited and put all my screen error.

Comment: @Astro Now it's too much 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my Errors through

```
npm audit fix --force
```

Answer (score 2):

i solved my this error by running this command

npm i url

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by these following steps:

1. According to the error, install the package `stream-http` using `npm i stream-http`
2. Use `npm i` then `npm audit fix --force`
3. Use `npm run eject` to eject the project
4. Find the file `./config/webpack.config.js`
5. Add `fallback` in the `resolve` config, and configure it `{ "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }`

Now `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```js
// a lot of consts and imports (requires)
// ...
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
  // a lot of configs
  // ...
  resolve: {
    // ...
    fallback: {
      http: require.resolve("stream-http") // that is this
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Webpack 5 no longer includes node shims by default, thus we must opt-in to all shims we want. We'll need to add a few dependencies to our project to accomplish this:

```sh
yarn add process browserify-zlib stream-browserify util buffer assert
```

after the installation, modify your `webpack.config` file as given below

```json
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  /* ... */

  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      http : require.resolve("stream-http"),
      https : require.resolve("https-browserify"),
      url  : require.resolve("url"),
      process: require.resolve("process/browser"),
      zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      util: require.resolve("util"),
      buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
      asset: require.resolve("assert"),
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
      process: "process/browser",
    }),
  ]

  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

version 0.27 [the latest] not works with me so I removed it and installed prev version like this:
"axios": "^0.21.1"
It works well with me

Answer (score 1):

Try delete `import {response} from "express"`

Maybe you don't want to use `response` from `express`.